# GitLab CI/CD configuration problem using shared runners

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, gitlab-ce

I have problems with GitLab CI/CD configuration - I'm using free runners on GitLab it self.
I have joomla (test) project using docker - I'm learng how it's work.
I created [.gitlab-ci.yml](https://gitlab.com/g00ntar/g00ntar-docker-joomla3-base/raw/master/.gitlab-ci.yml) with:

```
image: docker:latest
services:
  - docker:dind
```

at top of file.

On test stage I want run docker image created at the build stage.
When I add:

```
services:
    - mariadb:latest
```

to test stage I always [get](https://gitlab.com/g00ntar/g00ntar-docker-joomla3-base/-/jobs/157380228)
`Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?` at docker pull command. Without it I get error at docker run command at joomla image initialization cose of [lack of MySql server](https://gitlab.com/g00ntar/g00ntar-docker-joomla3-base/-/jobs/157383507)

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Try to add tag `docker` to you test stage in gitlab-ci.yml. Your CI is processed by shared-runners-manager-4.gitlab.com (and it hasn't docker tag - maybe it is the problem). Here is more about tags: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#tags

Comment: I don't thikn so that tags works this way (but I tried to add this tho ;]).

Comment: Yes adding tag "docker" solved your problem (it can connect Docker daemon now). But now you have new problem (Failed to connect to mariadb:3306)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set

```
services:
    - mariadb:latest
```

in your `test` job, this will override the globally defined `services`. Therefore, the docker daemon is not running during `test`. This also explains why you do not get the Docker daemon error when you omit the `services` definition for the `test` job.

Either specify the `docker:dind` service also for the `test` job, or remove the local `services` definition and add mariadb to your global `services` definition.

Comment: It is SO obvious now. Thanks alot